# Reading an open Excel file

Tags: r, excel, rodbc

I am trying to read an Excel file with `odbcConnectExcel2007` function from `RODBC` package. It works fine when the file is not in use. But when it is, I get the error:

> Warning messages: 1: In odbcDriverConnect(con, tabQuote = c("[", "]"),
>   ...) :   [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code -1028, message
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Cannot open database '(unknown)'. It
>   may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file
>   may be corrupt. 2: In odbcDriverConnect(con, tabQuote = c("[", "]"),
>   ...) :   ODBC connection failed

I have also tried to include `readOnly = TRUE` in the function specification, but still no luck. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: _"I am trying to..."_ do something - what does in look like in terms of lines of code?

Comment: why `RODBC`, imo there are better alternatives for reading in excel files, including `readxl`, `gdata` or `XLConnect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `read_excel()` function from the `readxl` package - it will allow you to read an Excel file into R while the file is in use.

Comment: Thank you for you advices, `read_excel` works well, so I'll switch to that.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If your question is answered you can click the check mark next to an answer so that others can see the question has been resolved.